# Automate the Redshift unload process?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-redshift

Hi Need your suggestion -

In redshift db i am comparing two table data and storing in table.The table data is changing every data i need to store this result set S3 by unload is there is way to automate this ,The data volume is less i can use lambda any one suggest me how to do it.

Create table diff as
(
SELECT *,'not in A' AS note FROM A1
EXCEPT
SELECT *,'not in A' AS note FROM A);

UNLOAD ('select * from diff')
TO 's3://object-path/name-prefix'
authorization
[ option [ ... ] ]

Comment: you have just posted this again rather than addressing the issues raised about what you are asking! - come on! here is your first post 11 HOURS AGO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48163875/need-aws-lambda-for-unload-data-from-redshift-db

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need AWS lambda for unload data from redshift db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48163875/need-aws-lambda-for-unload-data-from-redshift-db)

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks folks,I am able to achieve it i create a lambda tigger which run my dynamo db sql script place couple off sql script